# Wordpress how to get browser language?

Tags: wordpress, cookies

I'd like to ask how can I retrieve information on which language is picked in visitors browser? I tried:

```
<?php
$local = get_user_locale();
echo $local;
?>
```

to check if when I change browser language from PL to EN it could give me something like 'en-US'. Even though I switched browser language to English (US) and tried with incognito mode it keeps displaying that it's 'pl_PL'. Is there any different function that can check visitors browser language or region they're coming from?

I need it to be able to create cookie for GTranslate plugin after I get info about language. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Because ```get_use_locale()``` it's about a user's locale. In private session you are not logged in. You should be probably looking https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_locale/

Comment: Also have a look on this PHP page https://www.php.net/manual/en/locale.acceptfromhttp.php

Comment: @billybadass I tried to check what will get_locale() and locale_accept_from_http($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']) return. It turns out that on some browsers I get 'pl', on different one 'en', and when I tried to change language preferrenc in chrome setting to German it changed to 'de' but after changing lang preference to English it stayed 'de'. Clear cache and incognito didn't work. BTW I get different values returned on on subpage and the other subpage. What can I do with it?